# Saving an MS Office document to SharePoint prompts login

Tags: sharepoint-2010, microsoft-office-2010

When trying to save a new document directly from the Office 2010 program to a SharePoint 2010 document library the users are prompted to input credentials.

So far by adding ntlm-auth settings to Firefox and automatic logon for IE9 the users are not prompted to give their domain logon when trying to open the files.

How do I carry these settings over to apply to saving a new document as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your SharePoint site is an FQDN rather than a single name, you might want to try [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943280) registry modification and see if it helps.  There is no download, the functionality is included in Windows 7, you simply need to create the registry value.

1. Click **Start**, type **regedit** in the **Start Search** box, and then press **ENTER**.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters
3. On the **Edit** menu, point to **New**, and then click **Multi-String Value**.
4. Type **AuthForwardServerList**, and then press **ENTER**.
5. On the **Edit** menu, click **Modify**.
6. In the **Value data** box, type the URL of the server that hosts the Web share, and then click **OK**.
7. Exit Registry Editor.
8. Restart the **WebClient** service.

Comment: This method worked fine, it took several variations of the URL before it worked by entering in the format of 'http:// intranet.domain.com'. I wonder if there is a non-registry editing method to this but for now it is acceptable. Thanks.